# Solve $z^3=kx+ny$ , ($k\neq{n},k,n\in \mathbb{N}$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve $z^3=kx+ny$ , ($k\neq{n},k,n\in \mathbb{N}$)  for positive integer unknowns $x,y,z$

I have really no idea for this!!

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Crostul No analysis? What's the general form of them?

Comment: I would have expected $k x^2 + n y^2 = z^3$ with $\gcd(k,n) = 1.$ Where did you get your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g = \gcd(k,n)$.  There are integers $a,b$ such that $ak + bn = g$.
Let's suppose $a > 0$ and $b < 0$, and let $s = k/g$, $t = n/g$.  If $z^3 = u g$ is a cube divisible by $g$, then for any integer $j$ you can write

$$ z^3 = (u a - j t) k + (u b + j s) n $$

You want $x = u a - j t > 0$ and $y = u b + j s > 0$, i.e.
$$ -\dfrac{ub}{s} < j < \dfrac{ua}{t}$$
Since $a/t + b/s = 1/(st) > 0$, this is possible as long as $u$ is sufficiently large.